# Python Module and Class - AttributeError: module has no attribute

Tags: python, class, module

I'm new to python and I'm trying to create a module and class.

If I try to import `mystuff` and then use `cfcpiano = mystuff.Piano()`, I get an error:

```
AttributeError: module 'mystuff' has no attribute 'Piano'
```

If I try from `mystuff import Piano` I get:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Piano'
```

Can someone explain what is going on? How do I use a module and class in Python

mystuff.py

```
def printhello():
    print ("hello")

def timesfour(input):
    print (input * 4)


class Piano:
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = raw_input("What type of piano? ")

    def printdetails(self):
        print (self.type, "piano, " + self.age)
```

Test.py

```
import mystuff 
from mystuff import Piano 
cfcpiano = mystuff.Piano()
cfcpiano.printdetails()
```

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` file inside `mystuff` directory?

Comment: Can we see your complete file hierarchy?

Comment: `Test.py` and `mystuff.py` has to be in the same folder, for your code to work as is.

Comment: its a long shot .. But delete all the .pyc files from your folder

Comment: I dont have an init file, Im using Anaconda, created a project and then added a module.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a python module named `mystuff`

1. Create a folder with name `mystuff`
2. Create an `__init__.py` file

```py
#__init__.py

from mystuff import Piano #import the class from file mystuff
from mystuff import timesfour,printhello #Import the methods
```

3. Copy your class `mystuff.py` to the folder `mystuff`
4. Create file `test.py` outside the folder(module) `mystuff`.

```py
#test.py
from mystuff import Piano
cfcpiano = Piano()
cfcpiano.printdetails()
```

Comment: `mystuff.py` is not a class but a moule. What you described (the folder with `__init__.py` inside) is not a module but a package. You don't need that to create a python module.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the folder but it just couldn't find the module. I put all the code pages without Init page under one project and it seems to work. Two questions, how does the init page get fired? It seems to cache self data code - eg. If I alter the question to What is the age of the piano? this does not come up , how does one reset this? Thanks for the help guys.