# Python module has no attribute while the attribute exists

Tags: python

Taking help from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-access-python-package/), I was writing my own package. I have a folder `filter` which contains `__init__.py` (completely empty) and `pca.py`. `pca.py` has a class `pca` and that class has a method `performPCA` which takes two arguments. Then, I have this code:

```
from filter import pca
....
pca.performPCA(x,2)
```

When I run this, I'm getting an error

```
AttributeError: module 'filter.pca' has no attribute 'performPCA'
```

I know this question has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43200000/python-module-and-class-attributeerror-module-has-no-attribute), but I have everything that answer asks (the only difference is that my `__init__.py` is empty, which I think is totally fine). Please tell me where am I wrong. Thanks!

`test.py` goes as:

```
from filter import pca
print(pca)
import pandas as pd

x=pd.read_csv('Assignment-DS_gene_data.csv')
meta=pd.read_csv('Assignment-DS_Meta_data_sheet_.csv')
x.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0':'col1'}, inplace=True )
del x['symbol']
del x['col1']
p=pca.pca2
#print(p)
xNew=p.performPCA(x,2)
```

`pca.py` goes as:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

class pca2:
    #Choose this method if only projected data is required
    def perfromPCA(self,data,nComp):
        pcaModel = PCA(n_components=nComp)
        principalComponents = pcaModel.fit_transform(data)
        colNames = []
        for i in range(1,nComp+1):
            colNames.append('PC '+str(i))
        principalDf = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents
             , columns = colNames)
        return principalDf

    #Choose this method if plot and projected data both are required
    #For this, nComp can either be 2 or 3
    def performPCAPlot(self,data,nComp,metaData,column):
        principalDf = performPCA(data,nComp)
        if nComp == 2:
            plt.scatter(principalDf,data=metaData['column'])
            #plt.xlabel('PC1')
            #plt.ylabel('PC2')
            plt.show()
        else:
            fig = plt.figure()
            #to do
        return principalDf
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194109/discussion-on-question-by-ankit-kumar-python-module-has-no-attribute-while-the-a).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have another class inside `pca.py`, you should try creating an object first and then accessing it.

```py
from filter import pca
....
p = pca()
p.performPCA(x,2)
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it isn't working. I'm getting the error `'pca' object has no attribute 'performPCA'`

Comment: Did you try debugging? Maybe add a breakpoint and check what actually `pca` is and what attributes it does have?

Comment: This is the `p` in your code: `<filter.pca.pca object at 0x7f61f2899e48>`

Comment: I meant like an actual debugging using IDE, not just print statements.

Comment: Can you give me some hints on what should I do?

Comment: Try PyCharm CE. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941580/is-there-a-variable-explorer-for-pycharm.

Comment: You can also refer this. https://pedrokroger.net/python-debugger/. Install PyCharm > Add your project > Set a breakpoint at `p.performPCA(x,2)` > Debug the file > Check `p` in variables pane.

Answer (score -1):

Create an object first and then call the function on that object.

```
myPCA = pca()
myPCA.performPCA(x,2)
```

**Edit**

You are creating a python package by adding the _ *init* _.py file in the filter directory [further reading](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html#packages) subsection 6.4

You can import and use it like this (working for me with python 3.7.0)

```
from filter.pca import pca

myPCA = pca()
myPCA.performPCA(2,2)
```

or after renaming the class to pca2:

```
from filter.pca import pca2

myPCA = pca2()
myPCA.performPCA(2,2)
```

Comment: The proper instantiation should be pca.pca2()